# How to prevent background scroll on mobile when colorbox modal is active?

Tags: jquery, mobile, colorbox

I am trying to disable scrolling in parent page (in mobile browser) when colorbox modal is active.

I was able to achieve success in desktop browsers using the below code but doesn't work in mobile browsers.

```
jQuery(document).bind('cbox_open', function() {
    $.colorbox.resize();
    jQuery('body').css({ overflow: 'hidden' });
}).bind('cbox_closed', function() {
    jQuery('body').css({ overflow: '' });
});

jQuery(document).bind('cbox_open', function() {
    $.colorbox.resize();
    jQuery('html').css({ overflow: 'hidden' });
}).bind('cbox_closed', function() {
    jQuery('html').css({ overflow: '' });
});
```

Any pointers to resolve background scroll in mobile is appreciated.

Comment: add `position: relative;` to the body CSS. Also, your code is redundant, you can set the CSS of html and body in the same function by doing `jQuery('body,html').css`

Comment: Tip: `overflow: ''` should be `overflow: 'auto'`